# ¿Cómo crear un salto de línea en un placeholder de un <th>?

Tags: html5, bootstrap

Soy nuevo con html y boostrap, me gustaría saber cómo realizar un salto de línea en un elemento th de una tabla

Mi línea de código es la siguiente:

[image: Código]

Y el resultado que obtengo en la vista el siguiente:

[image: Tabla]

Necesito que se vea "¿Permisos para subir horas externas" en 2 líneas con el fin de visualizar toda la información, ¿existe alguna solución?

Sus comentarios serán de mucha ayuda

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Para esto, la solución no es un salto de línea. Los saltos de línea se utilizan para listas o para separar párrafos. Lo que tienes que hacer es que tu diseño sea responsive. Si eres nuevo, simplemente te recomendaría que le dieras un ancho más grande a la celda. Aquí te dejo un enlace del módulo CSS Grid, el cual es muy útil para este tipo de cosas, por si te interesa echarle un ojo https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te dice el compañero **@Macaroni** sería la mejor solución. Pero si el diseño no te permite hacer más grande la columna, ya sea por problemas de espacio o porque sencillamente sería un tamaño desproporcionado para luego rellenar el `input` con un "SI" o un "NO", como intuyo que sucederá, te ofrezco un par de pequeños truquillos para ver si te solucionan:

**Solución 1**

Ya que parece que estás usando **Bootstrap**, podrías poner en el `placeholder` simplemente "Permisos" y ampliar la información mediante un **tooltip**.

```
<input type="text" data-toggle="tooltip" title="¿Permisos para subir horas externas?" placeholder="Permisos">
```

**Solución 2**

Podrías usar un `text-area` en vez de un `input type="text"`. Estos te permiten definir el número de lineas que deseas que se muestren.

```
<textarea name="texto" cols="40" rows="2" placeholder="En un lugar de la mancha de cuyo nombre no puedo acordarme"></textarea>
```